# Brezis' exercise 6.2.3: $T(B)$ is not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> Let $E:=C([0, 1])$ be the Banach space with the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. We define a bounded linear operator $T:E\to E$ by
> $$
> Tu(t) := \int_0^t u(s) \, \mathrm d s
> \quad \forall u \in E, t \in [0, 1].
> $$
> Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $E$. Then $T(B)$ is not closed.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you have a check on it? Thank you so much for your help!

---

Let $u_n (s) := |s-\frac{1}{2}|^{1/n}$ and $v (s):= |s-\frac{1}{2}|$ for $n \ge 1$ and $s \in [0, 1]$. Then $u_n \in B, v \in E$ and $Tu_n (s) =|s-\frac{1}{2}|^{1/n+1}$. Then $\|Tu_n-v\|_\infty \to0$. Clearly, $v$ is not differentiable at $1/2$. On the other hand, $T(B) \subset C^1([0, 1])$. This completes the proof.

---

**Update 1** I made explicit computations as follows. Then I have realized that $v$ is smooth!!!

Let $u_n (s) := |s-\frac{1}{2}|^{1/n}$ and $v_n := Tu_n$. For $t \le 1/2$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
v_n (t) &= \int_0^t \left ( \frac{1}{2} -s \right )^{1/n} \, \mathrm d s \\
&= -\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}-t} s^{1/n} \, \mathrm d s \\
&= \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{\frac{1}{2}-t} s^{1/n} \, \mathrm d s \\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+1} s^{\frac{1}{n}+1} \bigg |^{\frac{1}{2}}_{\frac{1}{2}-t} \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1} \left ( \frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}+1}} - \left (\frac{1}{2} -t \right )^{\frac{1}{n}+1}  \right ).
\end{align}
$$

For $t > 1/2$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
v_n (t) &= \int_0^{1/2} \left ( \frac{1}{2} -s \right )^{1/n} \, \mathrm d s  + \int_{1/2}^t \left ( s-\frac{1}{2} \right )^{1/n} \, \mathrm d s \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}+1}} + \int_{1/2}^t \left ( s-\frac{1}{2} \right )^{1/n} \, \mathrm d s \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}+1}} + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+1} \left ( s-\frac{1}{2} \right )^{\frac{1}{n}+1} \bigg |_{\frac{1}{2}}^t \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1} \left (\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}+1}} + \left ( t-\frac{1}{2} \right )^{\frac{1}{n}+1} \right ).
\end{align}
$$

Let $v(t) := t$ for $t \in [0, 1]$. Then $\|v_n -v\|_\infty \to 0$.

Comment: Why is $T(u_n)(s)=|s-1/2|^{1/{n+1}}$? It does not seem like a primitive for $u_n$.

Comment: I have $T u_n(s) = n |s-\frac{1}{2}|^{1/n + 1} - \frac{n}{2^{\frac{1}{n} + 1}}$ (there might be a sign think to take care of in the first term). The point is that when you compute the infinite norm $\|T u_n - v \|_{\infty}$, I find something clearly diverging.

Comment: Your idea is fine. You should redefine $u_n.$ Let $v_n(t)=1/2^{1/n+1}-|s-1/2|^{1/n+1}$ and $u_n(t)=v_n'(t).$ Then $Tu_n=v_n.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have updated my thread with explicit computations and realized that my $v$ is smooth. Could you have a look at it and elaborate where I made a mistake. I expect that $v'$ is not continuous.

Comment: I have no idea where the mistake is. Why don't you start from the other end as I have suggested in my comment ? Then nearly no calculations are needed.

Comment: @NicolasAgote You're right. I have updated the thread with the correct one.

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois I think both your computation and my initial one for $v_n$ are wrong, Please see my update and below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My computation in **Update** is actually correct, so $u_n (t) = |t-\frac{1}{2}|^{1/n}$ will not work for the proof. As @Ryszard suggested in a comment, we let $v_n(t):=1/2^{1/n+1}-|t-1/2|^{1/n+1}$ and $v(t) := 1/2-|t-1/2|$ for $t\in [0, 1]$. Then $\|v_n -v\|_\infty \to 0$. Also, $v \in E$ is not continuously differentiable. Let $u_n (t) := v'_n (t)$. By FTC, $Tu_n (t) =\int_0^t u_n(s) \, \mathrm d s =v_n(t)-v_n(0) =v_n(t)$. Indeed,
$$
u_n (t) = - \frac{n+1}{n} \operatorname{sgn} \left (t-\frac{1}{2} \right ) \left |t- \frac{1}{2} \right |^{1/n}
\quad \forall t \in [0, 1].
$$